Discontinuous Collocation Methods
This is more or less a follow-up question of this question
In "Geometric numerical integration: structure-preserving algorithms for ordinary differential equations" on p.35, they generalize the class of collocation methods by introducing discontinuous collocation methods, defined as

Let $c_2, . . . , c_{s−1}$ be distinct real numbers (usually $0 ≤ c_i ≤ 1$), and let $b_1, b_s$ be two arbitrary real numbers. The corresponding discontinuous collocation method is then defined via a polynomial of degree $s − 2$ satisfying
$$\begin{aligned}
u(t_0)&=y_0-hb_1(\dot{u}(t_0)-f(t_0,u(t_0)))\\
\dot{u}(t_0+c_ih)&=f(t_0+c_ih,u(t_0+c_ih))\quad i=2,\ldots,s-1\\
y_1 &= u(t_1) - hb_s(\dot{u}(t_1) - f(t_1, u(t_1)))
\end{aligned}$$

While I think this is somewhat intuitive, i.e., you only collocate the ODE at the "in-between" points $c_2,...c_{s-1}$ (second equation). Additionally, the first equation basically says that there's a discontinuity of the polynomial $u(t)$ at $t=t_0$ which is proportional (or due to) to the error in the slopes. In other words $b_1$ is equal to the multiplier by which you need to go "along" this difference in slopes until you "reach" the true value $y_0$.
The same is true at the end of the interval.
The definition implies that this is only possible for $s\geq 3$ since for $s=2$ the second equation goes from $i=2,\ldots,-1$ which does not make sense.
Hairer and Wanner then introduce the following theorem:

The discontinuous collocation method of Definition 1.7 [above] is equivalent to an $s$-stage Runge-Kutta method with coefficients determined by $c_1=0,c_s=1$ and
$$\begin{aligned} 
&a_{i1}=b_1,\quad a_{is}=0,\ \text{for } i=1,\ldots,s\\ 
&C(s-2)\quad \text{and }\quad B(s-2)
\end{aligned}$$

With $C(q)$ and $B(q)$ being the simplifying assumptions mentioned in my other question.
However, they then state, e.g., that Radau IA methods are discontinuous collocation methods with $a_{i1}=b_1$, $b_1\neq0$ and $b_s=0$, i.e., they are discontinuous on the "left" interval and continuous on the right.
But IMO, while I agree that they are right-continuous, and see that "normal" collocation methods have $b_1=0$ and $b_s=0$, then, e.g., what about the one-stage (first-order) or two-stage (third-order) Radau IA methods with butcher tables
$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
0&0\\
\hline
& 1
\end{array}$$
and
$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
0& \frac{1}{4}&-\frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{5}{12}\\
\hline
& \frac{1}{4}&\frac{3}{4}
\end{array}$$
respectively, or any method with less than three stages, for that matter?
They neither fit into the definition that makes sense for $s\geq 3$ nor the theorem that states that $c_1=0$ and $c_s=1$.
The above theorem only fits for Lobatto IIIB methods since only these have $c_1=0$ and $c_s=1$ and $a_{i1}=b_1$ and $a_{is}=0$. However, they state that Radau IA methods are discontinuous collocation methods, too. What am I missing here?
